Telescopic Sum in $\displaystyle \arcsin$ form

If $\displaystyle S_{n}$


$\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{k=1}\sin^{-1}\bigg[\frac{(2k+1)}{k(k+1)\sqrt{k(k+2)}+\sqrt{(k+1)(k-1)}}\bigg]$


Then $\displaystyle 100\cos(S_{99})=$

I am Trying to convert it into $\displaystyle \sin^{-1}\bigg(\sin A\cos B+ \cos A\sin B\bigg)$
So we can write it as
$\displaystyle \frac{k+(k+1)}{k(k+1)\sqrt{k(k+2)}+\sqrt{(k+1)(k-1)}}=\frac{1}{(k+1)}\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k+2}}+\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(k+1)(k-1)}}$
But splitting above could not convert into $\displaystyle \sin (A+B)$ form
Please Help me How can I split into above form so that we can use Telescopic Sum
Thanks

Are you sure that you have copied the problem correctly?

Try to rationalise first

Wolfram shows a complicated closed form.

Hope this helps,
$$100\cos(S_{99})=100\cos\left(\displaystyle \sum^{99}_{k=1}\sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{(2k+1)}{k(k+1)\left(\sqrt{k(k+2)}+\sqrt{(k^2-1)}\right)}\bigg)\right)$$
Rationalizing the denominator;
$$100\cos(S_{99})=100\cos\left(\displaystyle \sum^{99}_{k=1}\sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{(2k+1)(\sqrt{k^2+2k}-\sqrt{k^2-1})}{k(k+1)(k^2+2k-k^2+1)}\bigg)\right)$$
$$100\cos(S_{99})=100\cos\left(\displaystyle \sum^{99}_{k=1}\sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{k^2+2k}-\sqrt{k^2-1}}{k(k+1)}\bigg)\right)$$
$$100\cos(S_{99})=100\cos\left(\displaystyle \sum^{99}_{k=1}\sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{(k+1)^2-1}-\sqrt{k^2-1}}{k(k+1)}\bigg)\right)$$
$$100\cos(S_{99})=100\cos\left(\displaystyle \sum^{99}_{k=1}\sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{k}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}}}-\frac{1}{k+1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{k^2}}}\bigg)\right)$$
$$100\cos(S_{99})=100\cos\left[\displaystyle \sum^{99}_{k=1}\left(\sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{k}\bigg)-\sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{k+1}\bigg)\right)\right]$$
$$100\cos(S_{99})=100\cos\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{100}\right]$$
Using $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=\sin(\theta)$:
$$100\cos(S_{99})=100\sin\left(\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{100}\right)$$
Using $\sin(\sin^{-1}x)=x, \, \forall\, x \in [-1,1]$
$$\boxed{100\cos(S_{99})=100 \times \frac{1}{100} = 1}$$

Your rationalization is wrong since the denominator in the question is
$$k(k+1)\sqrt{k(k+2)}+\sqrt{(k+1)(k-1)}$$
not
$$k(k+1)\bigg(\sqrt{k(k+2)}+\sqrt{(k+1)(k-1)}\bigg)$$

@mathlove, i believe the op has forgotten the extra pair of brackets
